# How can I access an object from an array list of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm so new in this and trying to create a commercial site on my own. Anyway,this is my object: users:

```
[{
  "id": "john_doe@yahoo.com",
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Email": "john_doe@yahoo.com",
  "Password": "john"
},
{
  "id": "janedoe@yahoo.com",
  "Name": "Jane Doe",
  "Email": "janedoe@yahoo.com",
  "Password": "jane"
}]
```

This is my code:

```
function addUser(e){
        id = $('#emailAccount').val();

        var name = $('#nameClient').val();      
        var email = $('#emailAccount').val();
        var psword = $('#passwordAccount').val();

        if (name == ""){
            alert("Field name cannot be empty.");   
            e.preventDefault();
        }else if (email == ""){
            alert("Field email cannot be empty.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }else if (psword == ""){
            alert("Field password cannot be empty.")
            e.preventDefault();
        }else {
            users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));

            //Check users

            if(users == null){
                users = [];         
            }
            var userList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));

            //new User object

            var new_user = {
                "id":id,
                "Name": name,               
                "Email": email,
                "Parola": psword                
            }

            users.push(new_user);
            localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

            console.log("User added")
        }

    }

});
```

I need to access the id from local storage and I don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: you mean to retrieve record on basis id ?? If this is true , you can't do that. you can get id as users[0].id

Comment: At which part you need to access the user id?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing/loading back an array, you need to loop all elements and access each element's property individually, for example:

```
$.each(users, function(i, user)
{ 
   console.log(user.id);
});
```

If you need specific elements, you can either access them by their index or use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to get them by a property value.

```
var foundUsers = users.filter(function(user) {
       return user.id === "john_doe@yahoo.com";
});
```

The filter function returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your object `object: users:` is an array, each element of this array is a `user object` , so there if you wist to extract `id`  at a particular index you can do something like `id = users[index].id`

you can also loop through your object get all the ids as follows

```
var id = [];
for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
id.push(users[i].id);    
}
```

I would advice you to use sessionStorage instead of local storage.

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('somekey', value);
window.sessionStorage.getItem('somekey');
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to parse the string using `JSON.parse()` and then loop through to get every value you need. See the working snippet below:

```js
var dataFromLocalStorage = `[{
  "id": "john_doe@yahoo.com",
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Email": "john_doe@yahoo.com",
  "Password": "john"
},
{
  "id": "janedoe@yahoo.com",
  "Name": "Jane Doe",
  "Email": "janedoe@yahoo.com",
  "Password": "jane"
}]`;

dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(dataFromLocalStorage);
dataFromLocalStorage.forEach(function(currentVal){
  console.log(currentVal.id);
});
```